# ¿Cómo llamar una función de javascript desde un método del Controller en MVC asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Por ejemplo, llamo a una vista parcial de esta forma desde la vista:

```
        function listar_lineas(fecha_comp,tipo_comp,pagina_comp,numero_comp){

            var url_action = '<%= Url.Action("partialListado", "Comprobante", new {fecha = "fecha_", tipo = "tipo_",pagina="pagina_",numero="numero_"})%>';
            url_action = url_action.replace("fecha_", fecha_comp).replace("tipo_", tipo_comp).replace("pagina_", pagina_comp).replace("numero_",numero_comp);

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: url_action,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#ListaParcial ").html(result);

                }

            });
        }

         function alertTes(mensaje){ //funcion que deseo llamar
            alert(mensaje);
         }

   <body>
    <div id="ListaParcial ">
    </div>
   </body>
```

Tengo un método de vista parcial en el controller, pero en el catch, quisiera llamar a una función de javascripts que está en definida en la vista:

```
    public PartialViewResult partialListado(DateTime fecha, string tipo, string pagina, int numero)
    {

        try
        {

          }
        catch (Exception error)
        {

            //Aquí deseo Llamar a la function alertTes(error.Message.ToString())
        }

        return PartialView(linea);
    }
```

Me gustaría saber como llamar a una función de javascripts definida en la vista desde un metodo del controller.

Answer (score 2):

Llamar a una función javascript (client) desde el servidor es un tanto complicado pues requiere una conexión en dos direcciones, probablemente comunicarse a través del protocolo websockets. En ese caso podríamos utilizar **SignalR**, que es una tecnología Microsoft que se encarga de proveer la infraestructura necesaria para esa comunicación.

**Referencia: http://www.asp.net/signalr**

---

> Pero en este problema especifico, no recomiendo hacer uso de ello,
> podemos hacer uso del manejo de errores propios del protocolo HTTP.
> Cuando una solicitud se ejecuta correctamente esta tiene un **código
> de estado 200 (OK)**, entonces para mostrar un error en el cliente
> podríamos devolver un **código de estado 400 (BAD REQUEST)**. Debido a
> que la idea de ASP.net MVC es el flujo solicitud-respuesta, **no seria
> la mejor opción llamar al cliente desde el servidor** para mostrar un
> mensaje, si no mas bien devolverle una respuesta que le haga saber que
> ha ocurrido un error.

Aplicándolo a este escenario...

```
public ActionResult partialListado(DateTime fecha, string tipo, string pagina, int numero)
{

    try
    {

      }
    catch (Exception error)
    {

       Response.StatusCode = 400;
       return Content(error.Message);
        //Aquí deseo Llamar a la function alertTes(error.Message.ToString())
    }

    return PartialView(linea);
}
```

Y en cuanto al cliente, manejaríamos la respuesta de la siguiente forma.

```
    function listar_lineas(fecha_comp,tipo_comp,pagina_comp,numero_comp){

        var url_action = '<%= Url.Action("partialListado", "Comprobante", new {fecha = "fecha_", tipo = "tipo_",pagina="pagina_",numero="numero_"})%>';
        url_action = url_action.replace("fecha_", fecha_comp).replace("tipo_", tipo_comp).replace("pagina_", pagina_comp).replace("numero_",numero_comp);

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: url_action,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ListaParcial ").html(result);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                  //Puedes usar tu funcion alertTest aqui
                  alert(errorThrown);
             } 

        });
    }

     function alertTest(mensaje){ //funcion que deseo llamar
        alert(mensaje);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

lo que te conviene en tu caso, es manejar la excepción de ajax, agregando el tag [AjaxHandleError].

```js
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: url_action,
  success: function (result) {
    $("#ListaParcial ").html(result);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
      //Puedes usar tu funcion alertTest aqui, me lo copie del del signalR
      alert(errorThrown);
  } 
});
```

```js
[AjaxHandleError]
public PartialViewResult partialListado(DateTime fecha, string tipo, string pagina, int numero)
{

  try
  {

  }
  catch (Exception error)
  {
      throw new ArgumentException("Ejemplo: " + ex.Message);
  }

  return PartialView(linea);
}
```

Comment: Hola @user2988031, el tag [AjaxHandleError] no me lo reconoce, acaso debo importar alguna librería o crear alguna clase de ella, ya que no me funciona el tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/jquery-ajax-error-handling-show-custom-exception-messages